# How to toggle back after previous view when using only command on vim?

Tags: window-management

I open multiple windows when using vim. Sometimes I want to only focus on one window for readability by using `:only` command or `Ctrlw-W o` shortcut. How do I get back to the multi split windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:only` closes all other windows in the current tab. And once a window has been closed it's gone. So there'll be no way "to get'em back" except to open the same number of windows while assigning same buffers. Kind of what a Vim session does.

So I prefer to maximize current window size while keeping all other open. This can be achieved by setting `:h 'winwidth'` and `:h 'winheight'` options. An example code:

```
" :Zoom
" toggle current window maximized
command! -bar Zoom
    \   if winnr('$') > 1 && &winwidth < 999
    \ |     let t:wrcmd = winrestcmd()
    \ |     set winminwidth=0 winminheight=0 winwidth=999 winheight=999
    \ | else
    \ |     set winminwidth& winminheight& winwidth& winheight&
    \ |     execute has_key(t:, 'wrcmd') ? remove(t:, 'wrcmd') : 'wincmd='
    \ | endif
```

This gives the following:

1. If switch to another window it'll get maximized too.
2. It is a global option, so it affects all tabs.
3. Some screen space will still be occupied by other window borders.

Comment: Thanks for this script.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is a mapping that opens the current window in its
own tab. Then I can just do `:q` to close it and return to the previous tab
(where all the windows are unchanged):

```
" open current split in own tab (like zoom in tmux) and keep cursor pos
nnoremap <LEADER>z mx:tabedit %<CR>g`x
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is to use the vim-aximizer plugin:
https://github.com/szw/vim-maximizer

It offers a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> to toggle between the window maximized and original window layout.